# How to import css files from react library inside libs to next.js app in nx integrated monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Can anyone help out on assets configuration in a nx next.js project.
I have multiple libs and one next.js project. I have got two problems

1. Some of these libs have imported .css files from node_modules but
   build failed due to global css conflict
2. How to export css files from libs and consume it in main apps

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, it seems that next 13.0.3 causes the imported global .css from node_modules to fail due to global css conflict constraint. From what I found, it only happen when the import statement is in the lib. If imported directly in the nextjs pages, the build is successful.

Temporarily Fix:

- Downgrade nextjs to 13.0.2 or
- Import the global css in the app instead

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.0.3 #42615

It seems that (not sure) this is the culprit that cause NX lib to import global css to fail in nextjs. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/42615